# TextMate-like bundle editor for Sublime Editor

Tags: text-editors, sublime-text-2, textmate

I know that Sublime Text has packages and also a package manager you can use to install additional bundles.

For example, I installed the Go bundle but I'd like to extend it by adding some custom shortcuts like the ability to define a function typing `func` + <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

I wonder, is there a bundle editor in Sublime Text like the one in TextMate that allows me to edit the bundle or add new snippets?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snippets can be created directly inside Sublime by choosing `Tools -> New Snippet...`. Read through [the docs](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html) and the [snippet reference](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/snippets.html) for details.

Sublime Text 2 stores its packages in `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages`, with a subdirectory for each package. However, these directories (and the files within them) can be overwritten when a package is updated, so it's best to save your custom snippets in the `Packages/User` directory. By using

```
<scope>source.go</scope>
```

in your snippet, it will only be active when you're editing Go files.